# How to make bundle.js load fast?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundle, webpack-dev-server

I am new to webpack and React.

I have an app with a signin page. User logs in and then starts using app.

But the signup page takes too long to load. Nothing appears until bundle.js file loads completely. I don't want to load whole bundle.js for just a single signin page.

I have implemented bundle.js in index.html in body tag like this. I also used async and defer attributes, but did not work.

```
<script src="/bundle.js?query=1.0.21"></script>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: You should grap blog articles that deal with the topic. Google "webpack bundle size"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [code splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), which is rather easy to achieve when using webpack. The idea to to create a separate bundle for each part of your web application, where it make sense. In your case it could be one bundle that just handles the login page so it's fairly small and quick to load and one bundle for the rest of your app.

You may also break that up in several other bundles, for example one per route or use [lazy loading](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) for some heavier components which will automatically load a specific js when the component is used by your app.